adb failure: usb_libusb.cpp:444 Check failed: packet_size == endpoint_packet_size
I have a MacBook Pro 2020 running on macOS 15.01. ADB is installed through Chocolatey. When no devices are connected:
engineer@MacBookPro platform-tools % adb devices
List of devices attached

engineer@MacBookPro platform-tools % adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 35.0.2-12147458
Installed as //Users/engineer/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
Running on Darwin 24.1.0 (arm64)

When an old table with Android 4.1 is connected
engineer@MacBookPro platform-tools % adb devices  
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/gq/0rs975rd2b9bj2h6zkymwx6r0000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 89657
--- adb starting (pid 89657) ---
12-21 01:08:08.048 89657 2909273 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
12-21 01:08:08.048 89657 2909273 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Version 35.0.2-12147458
12-21 01:08:08.048 89657 2909273 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Installed as //Users/engineer/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
12-21 01:08:08.048 89657 2909273 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Running on Darwin 24.1.0 (arm64)
12-21 01:08:08.048 89657 2909273 I adb     : main.cpp:63 
12-21 01:08:08.051 89657 2909277 F adb     : usb_libusb.cpp:444 Check failed: packet_size == endpoint_packet_size 

* failed to start daemon
adb: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon

However, it works on Windows 11 and this old Android 4.1 tablet PC.

I don't have a Mac handy to try it out, but what entitlements does your Terminal.app have? By default, it can't do everything.

What should it have?
